# Commuting Derivations on Regular Local $k$-algebra

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a regular local $k$-algebra, where $k$ is a field (of characteristic zero).  Let $x_1,\dots,x_n$ be a regular system of parameters, so that $dx_1,\dots,dx_n$ gives a trivialization of the module of differential forms over $R$.  Write $R_1=k\langle dx_1,\dots,dx_n\rangle$.

Then $R_1^*$ will naturally be a vector space of derivations on $R$, and in fact $R\otimes_k R_1^*$ will be isomorphic to the module of derivations on $R$.

For $X,Y\in R_1^*$, write $D_X$, $D_Y$ for the derivations on $R$ they give rise to.  Then my question is: do we have $[D_X,D_Y]=0$?  I.e. do $D_X$ and $D_Y$ commute, as linear maps?

I think it's straightforward to see that the derivation $[D_X,D_Y]$ vanishes on the subalgebra generated by $x_1,\dots,x_n$.  However, the $x_i$ do not generate all of $R$, so I'm not sure how to show this derivation vanishes completely (which I suspect is true).

Comment: Hint: what elements aren't in the subalgebra generated by $x_1,\cdots,x_n$? Do you know what a derivation must do to these elements?

Comment: Oh so every other element satisfies a polynomial equation over that subalgebra (perhaps not monic?  or is R integral over it?).  So you can choose one of minimal degree, apply this derivation, and get one of smaller degree.
Thanks!!